# sed for inserting multiple lines in a specific place in text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Even though I have checked the relevant questions about this, I could not find any solution. I think my problem is very simple, but I cant fix it lack of knowledge.

```
$statistics dscf parallel
$2e-ints_shell_statistics    file=DSCF-par-stat
$parallel_parameters
   maxtask=4000
   maxdisk=0
   dynamic_fraction=0.300000
$pardft
   memdiv=1
```

I want to add these multiple lines to a text file after when it sees "unix" word. So my code is something like this.

```
sed -i "/unix/a \\
$statistics dscf parallel \\
$2e-ints_shell_statistics    file=DSCF-par-stat \\
$parallel_parameters \\
   maxtask=4000 \\
   maxdisk=0 \\
   dynamic_fraction=0.300000 \\
$pardft \\
   memdiv=1 \\
" control
```

control is my output file. 
because of the $ sign the output lacks some parts of this insertion which looks like this.

```
$operating system unix
 dscf parallel
e-ints_shell_statistics    file=DSCF-par-stat

   maxtask=4000
   maxdisk=0
   dynamic_fraction=0.300000

   memdiv=1
```

I got a bit confused. I am open to any kind of suggestion. It does not have to be with "sed" command.

p.s: This is my first question here. :)

Answer (score 1):

with awk

```
awk '1;/unix/{print "$statistics dscf parallel\n\
$2e-ints_shell_statistics    file=DSCF-par-stat\n\
$parallel_parameters\n\
maxtask=4000\n\
maxdisk=0\n\
dynamic_fraction=0.300000\n\
$pardft\n\
memdiv=1"}' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thought i'd make the most of the last few hours :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/unix/ a\
$statistics dscf parallel\
$2e-ints_shell_statistics    file=DSCF-par-stat\
$parallel_parameters\
   maxtask=4000\
   maxdisk=0\
   dynamic_fraction=0.300000\
$pardft\
   memdiv=1\
' control
```

use simple quote around your sed action and a simple `\` at end of line to append

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed, cat & bash):

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '/unix/r /dev/stdin' file
$statistics dscf parallel
$2e-ints_shell_statistics    file=DSCF-par-stat
$parallel_parameters
   maxtask=4000
   maxdisk=0
   dynamic_fraction=0.300000
$pardft
   memdiv=1
!
```